# Reset Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

How can I reset all options in Resharper back to their default?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Here is how you do it in Resharper 6.1.

1. Go to Resharper -> Manage Options...
2. Click the "Reset All Settings" button.

Answer (score 13):

Try deleting the file:
`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\<resharper version>\vs<vs version>\UserSettings.xml`

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to exit visual studio, otherwise it would write them at exit time, but deleting this file and starting VS set me back to the default settings.