# How do you reset the ReSharper Code Inspection Settings in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have R# ReSharper 8 and Visual Studio 2013. I turned off some Code Inspection Settings that I want on. Instead of trying to figure out which setting I turned off, I would like to just reset them to their default values. How is that done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966798/reset-resharper this question probably help you

Comment: That says to: Go to Resharper -> Manage Options... -> Click the "Reset All Settings" button. That seems like a good option if there is no other way to specifically set Code Inspection Settings to their default values. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help you

1. Go to Resharper -> Manage Options...
2. Click the "Reset All Settings" button.

or try deleting following file

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\<resharper version>\vs<vs version>\UserSettings.xml
```

Comment: It made me start over with my configuration settings but at least made it possible to eventually do what I wanted to do.

Comment: I have issues with version 9 about Code Inspections. It seems that does not work properly with VS Community 2015.